# search through a two column dynamic array

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration

My application Passes one word taken from a textbox to a sub. I loaded some words in a two column dynamic array with so many rows. The array structure is like that:

```
David, Peterson

Fred , Alba

...  , ,,,,
```

I want if user typed for example David or Fred in the textbox, the application search through the array and send its correspondent value to the function. (in that example Peterson should be sent instead of david). Otherwise pass only the textbox text. But I don't know how to search through that array.

```
Dim MyArray() As String
Dim thestring as string
Private Sub Command_Click()
if textbox1.text'was in myarray then
    thestring=  'its correspondent value in the array
    Theeventsub thestring

else
    Theeventsub textbox1.Text
```

endif

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it VBA or VB6? Edit the tags accordingly please. You are missing an `End if`, your code isn't suppose to compile. To "search through" your array you can put a simple `For ... Next` loop that compares each string stored with the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

AS per your requirement we have to declare a two dimensional array with 2 columns and n number of rows.

```
Dim str_array(20, 2) As String ' array declaration
```

assume that the array having elements as follows, in the following array format:

```
fred   alex
paul   fem
gigi   gigo
jakson john
jack   mike
rose   frank
```

let **textbox1** is the search box and the **button1** is the search button. the code below will give the corresponding result for you:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
 For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count
 If str_array(i, 0) = TextBox1.Text Then
 MsgBox(str_array(i, 1))' gives the value as fem if the textbx1 having values paul
 ' replace the msgbox with function call
 ' if you need to pass value to anothe function
 End If
 Next
 End Sub
```